# PHP pagination calculation

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to teach myself the concept of how to calculate the indexes for pagination, I have found the following text:

> Say for example that we have per page equals to 10, so it will be ten
>   items per page. Once again our calculation for offset is per page,
>   which is ten, times the current page, minus 1. If the current page is
>   1, that calculation works out so that offset is 0, and that would mean
>   that records 1 through 10 would be 10, and that would mean that
>   records 11 through 20 would be returned

Maybe I'm looking at it the wrong way, but I don't get it.

The text states that using an example of 10 items per page, and we're on the first page, the formula should be:

10 * 1 - 1 -> this by my brain cramp should equal 9, but the text says it's 0

The next example they use is: 10 * 2 - 1 = 10, using normal math, is that not 19??

there's obviously something I'm missing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What they mean is

```
10 * (1-1) = 0
```

and

```
10 * (2-1) = 10
```

In the end this boils down to the fact that people count from 1 (the first page is page 1), but the offset starts at 0. So if you have a page-number, you need to lower it by one to get the offset number (the first page is 1, the first offset is 0 ).

THat means you first subtract (hence the brackets) and then multiply. The text is just a little bit confusing.

Comment: *facepalm* 

Thanks Nanne, I knew it had to be obvious!

Comment: Well, the text looks wrongish to me as well, the comma and all seems to imply that the subtraction would be last...

Comment: Yeah, it's actually a transcript from a tutorial video I think. It's possible the actual video would have shown the correct calculation for it